# How to send Latitude Longitude and Time and Daye with Id to server send Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

1I have Created try to write  latitude and Longitude using this Api

Also send Need to send  current time anda DATE

API : http://localhost/school/api/in-attendance/2?date=2023-11-30&in_time=11:00&lat=1&lng=2

2. {
   "success": false,
   "message": "Error.",
   "code": 404,
   "data": "YOU_HAVE_ALREADY_PUNCHED_IN_TODAY"
   }
3. {
   "success": true,
   "data": null,
   "message": "Your attendance been submitted successfully"
   }

Thanks

Please guide me how it is a crow

Comment: Explaine more your issue?

Comment: I want to send the current latitude and Longitude  and date and time to server.

Comment: do you try this package https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator